# Questions to the theme of "how do I get started doing XYZ"

Tags: discussion

Every now and then, questions come up that look like:

> Hello, I want to do XYZ. Can you suggest a plan of action?

or

> How can I get started building SuchAndSuch?

or

> I have no idea how to start making a SuperGizmo. Can someone point me in the right direction?

These questions are usually rather vague (or with a very broad goal), often lack basic details such as language/platform, but do show a lot of enthusiasm - they're not *bad* in the sense "failed to do basic research" or "has been asked a zillion times already", but they are certainly (at best) hard to answer.

What should be done with this type of question?

- Vote to close as off-topic/overly broad/too localized depending on contents?
- Leave a comment in the hope that the questioner narrows the scope down?
- Answer with a list of links/books/general advice/best wishes in their endeavor?
- Just ignore it and get on with life?

Comment: I'm resolutely in the "leave a comment" camp. Depending on the enthusiasm and evidence of research, I may or may not *also* leave a close vote.

Comment: There was just recently a question asked about how to prompt or otherwise encourage users to provide more information along with their questions (i.e., how to solve the *source* of this problem), but alas I can't find it. I suspect it was deleted, and I infuriatingly don't have 10k+ on Meta...

Comment: well there [What's the protocol for teaching people to ask better questions?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74675/whats-the-protocol-for-teaching-people-to-ask-better-questions) that actually fits pretty well with solving the _source_ of the issue. Both answers make sens too. (Hadn't thought about searching for that.) What's the protocol here? should I vote/flag as dup, or delete this?

Comment: You can vote to close if you want, but I don't know that this is an *exact* duplicate. Solving the source of the problem is certainly useful, but your question is specific to the *response* the community thinks is most appropriate. That's got value, too, as I don't think we're actually going to fix it. I'd leave it open for a while. (That wasn't the question I was thinking of, btw.)